# How to select best kernel parameters for radial basis function of SVM with fingerprint recognition?

Tags: svm

Here, I am using RBF function of SVM for fingerprint verification and matching. Please tell me What is the approximate range of sigma and gamma values in RFB for fingerprint recognition.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As this site is read by many for whom English is a second (or third or fourth) language, it's best to avoid slang like 'plz' which I changed to 'please'. Also, it might be good to spell out RBF and SVM. Abbreviations can suffer in translation.

Comment: Your question in the title is different from the one in the body of the text. Are you interested in what are the best parameter values or what is the best *range* of parameter values?

Answer (score 2):

It's really going to depend on what your data look like, and what features you have selected. In some ways, this is still an open question, and one occasionally sees it in critiques of SVMs (i.e. novice users don't have a good intuition for how to tune the parameters).

If you want to start with a principled approach, [this paper](http://web.archive.org/web/20100409140152/http://nyc.lti.cs.cmu.edu/yiming/Publications/icml97.ps) might be a suitable starting place.

If you just want to do the tuning and get things working, you can start fiddling with the parameters a bit. When I was learning this several years ago, I found setting one parameter to one, and then varying the other by order of magnitude provided a good feel for their effects.

Comment: just to give an impression of the parameter range, grid.py tool from the libSVM package checks values of C from 2^-5 to 2^15 and gamma from 2^-15 to 2^3

Comment: Thank You Sir,but I am using svmlight tool and I will get 68 features using geometry and zernike moment analysis,after using PCA I will get reduced feature vector upto 20 features,then I will use SVM for feature verification and classification,so what should be the range of SVM kernel parameters ??

Comment: I am doing fingerprint matching according to image id, if id matches of both the test image and template image then I will go for fingerprint verification and classification using SVM. How does SVM classify feature vectors of database images, which criteria it uses? I mean which of the classes that I am getting after using SVM, and how will SVM verify the matched image?

Comment: The link to the paper is broken, could you pls provide some information so one can find it? Thanks

Comment: Luckily, the Internet Archive holds a snapshot of the page referenced in the accepted answer. You can find it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100409140152/http://agbs.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/km/bb/showthread.php?tid=1350).

Comment: @Dexter I've now fixed the link in the question so that it points directly to the author's academic website instead. Hopefully this will be more stable over time.